# One way traffic between azure VPN and on-prem

Tags: azure

I created a Virtual Network (VPN) on Azure and provided an ample address space 10.0.0.0/16, then I made a couple subnet within the network, one for the gatewaySubnet (10.11.1.x), and another for the VMs inside (10.11.0.x), I can go though and ping to the other side, but the other side cannot ping me.

I tried this windows batch program:

```
:loop
curl http://10.11.x.x/
goto loop
```

however, the inbound traffic doesn't flow through.

I don't understand if I should use the route command on their side so that they have fixed routes, I also don't know how to monitor the traffic within the azure vm, I'm using a basic RouteBased VPN with no BGP.

Frankly, after a couple days of pulling my hair, I'm ready to give up the whole VPN idea.

Comment: Unless this is just the case with your examples, you are referencing subnets that are not inside your larger range. (`10.0.0.0/16` includes `10.0.0.0` through `10.0.255.255`)

Answer (score 1):

try to see this link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways

Maybe this is better than to pull your hair. ;)

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Please do not post link only answers, as they are prone to link rot. Relevant info should be included in the post.